# Can I delete files from Magento MAGMI Image import directory?

Tags: image, magento, magmi

Can I delete the original image files from the MAGMI import directory

Just in case everyone's installations are not the same as mine, let me  explain
I have a magmi directory that is not in my main html directory on my server.
When I want to import a new csv file with products, I upload all of the images into this directory

/magmi/html/media/import

After I successfully import the new products, it copies (not moves) the images to the directory where my magento installation lives, which is

/html/media/catalog/product/(folders with the first letter or number of the image filename)

It also copies them into a similar directory in the MAGMI installation. Not sure why

magmi/html/media/catalog/product/(folders with the first letter or number of the image filename)

My questions is, can I delete all of the original image files in the MAGMI directories once I have successfully imported the csv files? even the ones in 
magmi/html/media/catalog/product/(folders with the first letter or number of the image filename) ?

Because it's getting out of control now. Like almost 2GB of images that I have a feeling are not necessary. there are 3 copies of every image on my server

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete Magmi after running the imports.

Magento uses the `/media/` located in the Magento root folder to store it's image files.  Anything within the Magmi directory is not likely being used and is safe to be removed.